# Cypress task fails and complains that task event has not been registered in the plugins file

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using the cypress `cy.task()` method/ function to copy a `csv` file from one directory to another directory. Below is my `cy.task('copycsvFile')` and relevant code written in `support/index.js` file. While running it throws following error; 
CypressError: cy.task('copycsvFile') failed with the following error:
`The 'task' event has not been registered in the plugins file. You must register it before using cy.task()` Any idea why this is not recognised ?

Node version : v10.15.3, 
Cypress version : 3.1.5

//sample-spec.js file

```
cy.task('copycsvFile');
```

Below is my `index.js` file 
// support/index.js file

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (on) => {
    on('task', {
        copycsvFile: (Obj)=>{
          var fs = require('fs');
         fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/SomeName/Downloads/Export_Survey_CSV.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('C:/User/Client/Client - Cypress Web UI Tests/cypress/fixtures/Export_Survey_CSV.csv'));
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last, I have figured out the answer.
I have added the below code in the wrong location and that was the reason it fails and returned the above error.
Now I have corrected the location and added under `plugins/index.js` and works perfectly.

I've also made a small change, ie I added `return null` since I didn't have anything to return in my case.

// In my spec file;

```
cy.task('copycsvFile');
```

// added below code under.. /plugins/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
    
module.exports = (on) => {
  on("task", {
    copycsvFile: (Obj) => {
      var fs = require("fs");
      fs.createReadStream(
        "C:/Users/SomeName/Downloads/Export_Survey_CSV.csv"
      ).pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(
          "C:/User/Client/Client - Cypress Web UI Tests/cypress/fixtures/Export_Survey_CSV.csv"
        )
      );
      return null;
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, different solution for me though.
Since upgrading to Cypress 10, this approach(support/index.js) is no longer supported, see: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#cy-task

Comment: This is working at your end?

Comment: I have written like shown in the image but it still not working [https://ibb.co/dKzw3fw ]