# Cypress: The 'task' event has not been registered in the plugins file. You must register it before using cy.task()

Tags: cypress

I am writing the end-to-end tests using Cypress for my web application. In my tests, I am trying to create a task, https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task. But it is throwing an error. Here is what I did.

I declared a task in the plugins/index.js file as follow.

```
module.exports = (on) => {
    on("task", {
        setTestId(id) {
            testId = id;
            return null;
        },
        getTestId() {
            return testId;
        }
    });
};
```

Then I use the task in the test as follow.

```
cy.task('setTestId', 7654321);
```

When I run the tests, I am getting the following error.

```
The 'task' event has not been registered in the plugins file. You must register it before using cy.task()
```

As you can see, I tried this solution as well, [Cypress task fails and complains that task event has not been registered in the plugins file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253396/cypress-task-fails-and-complains-that-task-event-has-not-been-registered-in-the). It did not work either. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing some formatting (":" and "=>" and such). Try this:

```
module.exports = (on) => {
  on("task", {
      setTestId: (id) => {
          testId = id;
          return null;
      },
      getTestId: () => {
          return testId;
      }
  });
};
```

Set the testId as you did:

```
cy.task('setTestId', 7654321);
```

And when you want to retrieve the testId, use:

```
cy.task('getTestId').then((testId) => {
   cy.log(testId)
});
```